# Error: 1Helper could not be found. - cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create a index method for the content model controller and I am getting the following error, I searched here but did not find the relevant answer. Please take a look at the following code and screenshot:

Content.php:

```
class Content extends AppModel{
   public $name = 'Content';
}
```

ContentsController.php:

```
class ContentsController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Contents';
    public function index() {
        $this->set('Contents', $this->Content->find('all'));
    }
}
```

index.ctp:

```
<h1>View All Content</h1> 
<table>
     <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Content</th>
     </tr>
     <?php foreach ($Contents as $content) : ?>
         <tr>
             <td><?php echo $this->$content['Content']['id']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $this->$content['Content']['title']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $this->$content['Content']['content']; ?></td>
         </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Screenshot:
http://postimg.org/image/sslcgoutx/

Please help as I am new to cakephp and learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in index.ctp

```
<h1>View All Content</h1> <table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($Contents as $content) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $content['Content']['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $content['Content']['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $content['Content']['content']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

Comment: glad this helped you .. please go through cakephp.org tutorials and documentation.